# Kubernetes: shutdown node between jobs runs

Tags: cron, kubernetes, shutdown

I run a Kubernetes CronJob every week, on a Kubernetes cluster that have a single node in it. It runs on Google Compute Engine.

I would like to shutdown the node completely between two jobs, for billing purposes (we pay the price as if the machine was used for the whole week but it is actually useful a few hours)

Is it possible boot the node, run the job, then shutdown the node?

Comment: This question rather belongs to serverfault I think...

Answer (score 0):

The cluster autoscaler can help with this:

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler